# floats inside a position:relative container

Tags: html, css

I wanted to put a `float` inside a

```
.wrapper {
 position:relative;
 }
```

but when i do, the layout messes up.

http://jsfiddle.net/pedenski/6uKkv/

below is the layout i wanted to happen.

[image: float inside a relative position]

Answer (score 0):

You can change width and height from following:

http://jsfiddle.net/6uKkv/3/

Comment: hi, i already did that, but if you look closely the shadow borders disappear "http://i47.tinypic.com/2hsc187.png" when you put float